# Illustrator warp effect not editable

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, cs4

I am having a problem with effects in Illustrator CS4.

I applied a warp effect to a path. Normally, when I want to modify the warp effect, I go to my Appearance panel and click on the Warp: Arc link. See screen grab on the left.

But I just opened an image I was working on earlier and noticed that the Warp: Arc link has vanished. See screen grab on the right.

I am pretty sure I didn't accidentally expand the path, because when I select it I can see that it is still a straight line but with a warped appearance. There also seems to be what looks like an arc icon at the top of the panel, above the eyeballs. I never normally pay attention to what's going on with this icon, but I am guessing it means that the path has an arc effect applied to it.

Is there anything I can do to 'reinstate' the effect that I assume is still there somewhere?

Thanks for reading. I tried searching for a solution, but I mustn't be using the correct terminology because I couldn't find anything relevant.

[image]

Comment: Could be part of the stroke.. can't see that from your screen shot.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're right. I wasn't aware that it was possible to do that. I must have dragged it in there accidentally. Thanks, Scott!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to apply effects to individual strokes and fills in the Appearance Panel.

So...

You can have the effect applied at the object level:

[image]

Or you can have the effect applied at the stroke or fill level:

[image]

My guess is you have it applied at the stroke level and your second screen shot isn't expanded enough to show it.